# How to pass a socket connection around in Flux?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, flux, reactjs-flux

How should a socket be initialised once and passed around a React/Flux application? Should there only be one socket object for the application? Should it be initialised in a component then passed through to actions then the store?

Comment: In my opinion, each client only has one socket to communicate with the server so there should be one singleton class which manage the socket initialization. `emit` event should be called in Store or Action, and you should have a WebAPI to receive data from `on` event and then call actions. In fact, focusing on data coming in is more important than data coming out in Flux architecture.

Comment: @PhiNguyen Can you give an example of how you would initialise the socket? (not with ecma6 please)

Answer (score 0):

This is from https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns React.14/ReFluxWebSocket.

```js
import Actions from '../flux/Actions';

module.exports = {
  socket: {},
  init() {
    this.socket = new Primus();
    this.socket.on('server:GotData', this.gotData);
    Actions.apiInitDone();
  },
  getData() { this.socket.send('client:GetData', {}); },
  gotData(data) { Actions.gotData1(data); Actions.gotData2(data); Actions.gotData3(data); },
  setData(data) { this.socket.send('client:SetData', data); },
};
```

What I do is call the init function and then let the apiInitDone action trigger the initial data load.